# Jquery XML DOM?

Tags: jquery, xml, dom, namespaces

I want to have some jquery codes that can get the data inside < a:title> and < b:title> separately but it is difficult to do it. I have taken some trials and read some posts about the jquery to get tag with namespace. It seems that there is no way to handel tag with namespace in jquery.

The XML received:

```
<A:entry>
<a:title>title</a:title>
<a:info>info</a:info>
<a:time>21345</a:time>
<b:group>
    <b:title>btitle</b:title>
    <b:info>binfo</b:info>
    <b:time>ctime</b:time>
</b:group>
</A:entry>
```

To get the tag < a:title>, I tried:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function(result)
    {
        $(result).find('title').each(function() {console.log($(this).text());});
    },
    dataType: 'xml'
});
```

However, it **also** gets the < b:title>.

To get the tag < b:title>, I tried:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function(result)
    {
        $(result).find('group title').each(function(){console.log($(this).text());});
    },
    dataType: 'xml'
});
```

**It doesn't work at all**. I read the document and function 'find' can take selector as input but I wonder why ancestor-descendant selector does not work...

Can someone provide me some example codes?

Should I regards XML object as DOM in jquery? How should I understand XML object in jquery? In html DOM, the selectors mentioned in jquery documents would work earily. I'm confused.

Comment: `dataType: xml` should be `dataType: "xml"`, otherwise you might get html rather than xml and it might not get parsed properly.

Comment: `<a:time>21345<a:time>` isn't closed properly

Comment: O...just typos. Edited.